# How can I put a plot on GUI in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, racket

I have a GUI application and I to am trying to insert a genetated by the `plot` library plot into it.
Can I put the plot in an existing GUI element, like panel, canvas, or something else? There seem to be no such parameters in the plot library functions. And if I try to create the plot in a separate window with functions like `plot-frame` or `plot3d-frame`, no window is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to zoom an rotate you can use plot-snip. The plots in DrRacket are plot-snips. To show them in a GUI first insert an editor% and then use the insert method to insert the plot-snip.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find out how to insert plot-snip, but found nothing. Hope that will bring me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that such functions do exist in the library: [plot/dc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/plotting.html?q=plot#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._plot%2Fdc%29%29) and [plot3d/dc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/plotting.html?q=plot#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._plot3d%2Fdc%29%29).
However, the result is a static image, so you can't zoom or rotate it.